# Help Please hardhat.config.js * Invalid account: #0 for network: Rinkeby - private key too short, expected 32 bytes

Tags: ether, metamask, hardhat, smart-contract-wallets, hardhat-deploy

Hi Please i get this error while compiling  hardhat.config.js  :  * Invalid account: #0 for network: Rinkeby - private key too short, expected 32 bytes
i have my private key in dot env copied from metamask please how to i convert the normal private key into 32 bytes and how do i solve this thanks in advance here's my code

```
/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */

     require('dotenv').config();
     require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
    
     const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env
    
     module.exports = {
      solidity: "0.7.1",
      defaultNetwork: "Rinkeby",
      networks: {
        hardhat: {},
        Rinkeby: {
          url: API_URL,
          accounts: ['${PRIVATE_KEY}']
        }
      }
      }
```

error :

```
  * Invalid account: #0 for network: Rinkeby - private key too short, expected 32 bytes
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you are copying your PRIVATE KEY and not your PUBLIC KEY.

If you are using metamask, you can get your PRIVATE KEY from

- the 3 dots menu beside your public key,
- and then account details
- then export private key

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case key was from alchemy

https://wiki.polygon.technology/docs/develop/alchemy/

this is extremely bugged tutorial, no recommend nobody but finally

i converted my API_KEY to hex using

```
const hex = utf8ToHex(PRIVATE_KEY ?? '');
```

and this hex in cofig

```
const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  solidity: "0.8.9",
  defaultNetwork: "polygon_mumbai",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {},
    polygon_mumbai: {
      url: API_URL,
      accounts: [`0x${hex}`],
      chainId: 8
    }
  },
};
```

below function

```
function utf8ToHex(str: string) {
  return Array.from(str).map(c =>
      c.charCodeAt(0) < 128 ? c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) :
          encodeURIComponent(c).replace(/\%/g,'').toLowerCase()
  ).join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing string extrapolation correctly, you should be using `, the tilde button. Read more [here](https://careerkarma.com/blog/javascript-string-interpolation/#:%7E:text=JavaScript%20string%20interpolation%20is%20the,into%20a%20string%20using%20interpolation.).

Answer (score 0):

if you copy PRIVATE_KEY from Metamask, you should put `0x` as prefix

Answer (score 0):

In hardhat.config.js, accounts key value should be an array of hex-encoded private keys, for that you need to add the `0x` as prefix of your Matamask private key before passing this private key to the account array
as below

```
networks: {
    goerli: {
      url: RCP_GOERLI_URL,
      accounts: [`0x${process.env.RCP_PRIVATE_KEY}`],
      chainId: 5,
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be a bit late to this problem given above, if none of the answers given above worked for you, (which was my case), you can simply add `0x` before your metamask private key in your `.env` file.